# AWS Cognito TLS enforcement

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We nee the authorization url (e.g. `https://user_pool.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com`) to enforce TLS 1.2 or higher.

I cannot see a way to enforce this on the user pool or anywhere else, but if there is a way, can someone share it?

[Saw this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70374591/aws-cognito-network-traffic-flow-related-question) and did some of my own digging, and I see the [FIPS endpoints](https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/fips/).

We are using OIDC discovery (using the nodejs "openid-client" package) to retrieve the auth url, so I tried changing the issuer URL from `cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` to `cognito-idp-fips.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

However, the auth url returned in the discovery is still the same - it's not the FIPS URL, and indeed, if I go to `https://cognito-idp-fips.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_user_pool/.well-known/openid-configuration` I see that it returns the "regular" URLs and not the `-fips` variants.

So how do I get this working??

Yours Truly,

Frustrated with AWS